# Use modern definition of differentiability to prove |x| is not differentiable at x = 0

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> The classic definition of differentiability is $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x + h) - f (x)}{h}$ exists.
>
> The modern definition of differentiability is $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{R(h)}{h} = 0$ where $R(h)$ = $f(x + h) - L(h)$. $L(h) = f(x) + ah$ where a is the slope of tangent line at point x.

To prove |x| is not differentiable at x = 0, I need to show that $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{R(h)}{h} \neq 0$.

Thus, by definition, $R(h) = f(0 + h) - L(h) = f(0 + h) - f(0) - ah$. Then I take the limit of R(h), which get $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(0 + h) - f(0) - ah}{h} $.
Simplify the limit I get $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|h| - ah}{h}$. Then how can I proceed?

Comment: The title is wrongly stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h>0$ then we have $$\frac{h-ah}{h}=1-a$$
and if $h<0$ we get $$-1-a$$
Both terms are different. So no limit exists.